# Using dependencies to create a FIFO NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, fifo

I've created a NSOperationQueue subclass, set maxConcurrentOperations to 1, and have overridden the `addOperation` method to be the following:

```
-(void)addOperation:(NSOperation *)op
{
    // If there are already operations on the queue, add the last operation as a dependency to the delay. Ensures FIFO.
    if ([[self operations] count] > 0) [op addDependency:[self.operations lastObject]];
    [super addOperation:op];
}
```

This was suggested here somewhere (I don't have the link at hand). The trouble is that I occasionally get a crash here:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

At crash time, [[self operations] count] == 0, so presumably in the nanoseconds between the check [[self operations] count] > 0, and the addDependency call, the last operation on the queue finished executing, and became nil.

My question is, how do I work around this?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap `addDependency` in a try-catch block? Then you could handle the exception by just not adding the dependency.

Comment: Actually no! That's a wonderful idea... I actually forgot about the existence of try-catch since I started coding Obj-C.

Comment: I added an answer using the try catch approach.

Comment: Exceptions in Objective-C do stack unwinding and probably will leak memory (release statements in your code are never executed).  Ideally you would just prevent it from happening in the first place.

Comment: BTW, if you had multiple threads adding operations, you have a race condition between the adding of the dependency and adding of the operation. If you're going to go down this road, you should synchronize this process.

Comment: I agree with @CharlesA. that using exception handling is _not_ the correct way to handle this. One should prevent the exception from happening in the first place rather than catching the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this `NSInvalidArgumentException` issue, just establish a local reference to the `lastObject` for the duration of this method and then test that:

```
NSOperation *lastOperation = [self.operations lastObject];
if (lastOperation) [op addDependency:lastOperation];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot fix the crash you could at least wrap the `addDependency` in a try-catch block:

```
-(void)addOperation:(NSOperation *)op {
    @try {
        if ([[self operations] count] > 0) [op addDependency:[self.operations lastObject]];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // ignore    
    }
    @finally {
        [super addOperation:op];
    }
}
```

This would at least avoid the crash.